# dual installation of ubuntu WSL using Microsoft Store

Tags: software-installation

I am new to ubuntu and I have installed ubuntu 18.04lts Microsoft version via Microsoft Store to use it in windows 10 and when I tried to install the latest version of ubuntu 20.04 from the same store I got dual versions on my system, what I already have 18.04, in addition to the newest one 20.04 but.

I noticed something strange from the beginning  and I don't know why the newest version is in grey colour and also has a Hush sign to indicate that it's windows environment while the old one has the tilde sign, as usual, to indicate a Linux environment.
the picture clarifies what I am telling if anyone can explain to me why the newest version is grey, is it because it's not installed correctly or because of the existence of the old version,
it would be appreciable, thanks in advance

[image]

do I have to remove or uninstall the old version?

Comment: First off this is WSL.  Secondly, you can have multiple Linux environments in WSL.  The newest version is 'grey' because you're in the `root` logon - the Linux equivalent of superuser - and it doesn't have the color profiles for your Bash profile (from `.bashrc`) in it by default.  That's normal if you've just installed it and not closed out yet.  Have you tried typing `exit` on the 20.04 window, to try and get out of the root prompt?

Comment: I ask this because I've got both versions on my work computer **and running concurrently** without this problem you're having.

Comment: thanks so much, brother Thomas but I haven't tried this exit on the 20.04 window yet I will try using the same commands as before to see what I will get

Comment: all commands are working fine by the way and what I was expecting is to have the same root on both versions but the newest one has really some changes but it's okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry. you are just logged in in the wsl as `root` user. you need to log in into the normal user for it to be not gray.

Comment: yes dear I know it's WSL and I forgot that I didn't set any users name or passwords I headed just for asking without thinking about it but what I was really wondering about is the difference between the two versions signs why it's not a tilde ~ like the old version this is also cleared for me as a the root path will be changed but thank you so much

Comment: ~ means the home directory. and the $ sign is only in the normal user. root has the # sign.

Comment: also, I am using Ubuntu on the virtual box but wanted to try this Microsoft app to differentiate between both of them